# max of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

Given an array of values `[1,2,0,-5,8,3]`, how can I get the maximum value in JavaScript?

I know I can write a loop and keep track of the maximum value, but am looking for a more code-efficient way of doing so with the JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Second result from 'max of array in javascript' on google ^

Comment: Agree, maybe edit the other to include the word armax though... Coming from python, that's what I instictively googled and nothing came up...

Comment: I would say it has a reasonable title. Regardless of language, I would have search 'max of array in <language>', but that's just me.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [ES6 spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
let array = [1, 2, 0, -5, 8, 3];

console.log(Math.max(...array)); //=> 8
```

Comment: Or without the spread operator `Math.max.apply(false, arr)`

Comment: The spread operator is not **efficient**.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir There is no spread 'operator', [it's syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44934830/5647260).

Comment: @AndrewLi The three-dot-thing, whatever its real name is..., It's just the worse regarding effeciency.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Is it? I tested and against `reduce` it sometimes wins and sometimes loses. Plus efficiency shouldn't even matter, we're talking less than 1 millisecond.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yeah! I don't care about few milliseconds myself. But OP said _efficient way_, so... + When the array get big (talking about seconds) then the spread **syntax** becomes a headache.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, IIRC `Math.max` is also restrained to the max length like `Array#push` is with spread syntax. But `reduce` wouldn't exactly be volumes faster.

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm not advocating `reduce` neither. `reduce` is also not as efficient as a sweet & simple `for` loop. Last time I did a test: reduce was about `x10` slower than a `for` loop and `spread syntax` was `x40` slower than `for` loop. Thus, if OP is looking for efficiency, he has to use `for`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir By efficiency, what I think the OP meant was a more concise version, than a regular for loop.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `Math.max(...arr)` will likely be somewhat slower than `Math.max.apply(null, arr)` but nowhere near as 'not efficient'. Neat JS features are almost always a trade-off. If you have other information that can be proven with numbers, please, consider providing an answer in dupe question. Even though this has been discussed on SO countless times, new good answers are always good.

Comment: `Math.max(..arr)` will typically be compiled into `Math.max.apply`, so there's **no** performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
yourArray.reduce((max, value) => {return Math.max(max, value)});
```

The `reduce` will itterate over values in the array, at each time returning the maximum of all of the values before the current one.

Comment: Or just `( … ) => …` for an implicit return ...

Comment: Also, why through the trouble of a reduce operation when spread syntax exists??

Comment: You might want to provide some reasonable default value that is returned when the array is empty, such a `0`, `-1` or `-Infinity`.