# Spread syntax ES6 with statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next, spread-syntax

I tried to write ternary operator with spread syntax and copy two objects. Is it possible to use ternary operator with spread syntax inside with literal objects?  My code works okay, I just want to optimize it.

```
hintStyle: disabled ? {...globalStyles.hint, ...globalStyles.hintDisabled} : globalStyles.hint,
```

I want to write like this:

```
hintStyle: {...globalStyles.hint, {disabled ? ...globalStyles.hintDisabled : {}}},
```

Comment: Does it work? If not, do you get errors? If so, what errors? What's the question you're asking?

Comment: My first code works , how to use spread es6 operator with ternary operator inside. The error is 'Unexpected token'

Comment: don't you need a spread operator before `{disabled ? ...globalStyles.hintDisabled : {}}`

Comment: Rest spread is transpiled to Object.assign invocation, which certainly can be written in form with conditional argument applying

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Spread [is *not* an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572), it's part of the object literal syntax (or at least it will be when the proposal is accepted). You need to write

```
{...globalStyles.hint, ...(disabled ? globalStyles.hintDisabled : {})},
```

Comment: What if you only want to spread in one case bot not in the other? Lets say string vs array is the check.

Comment: @TheFool You can only spread an object into an object. If you have a value that is not an object, how do you want to make it part of the object?

Comment: you can spread one array into another or you can just add another item

Comment: @TheFool This question is not about arrays though. Do *you* use array spread syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem today, my use case was simple enough that I could do this:

```js
// given any-typed parameters a and b, I want to append b to a
// if a is iterable, I want to use spread.
// Initially I had:

const fn1 = (a, b) => [Symbol.iterator in a ? ...a : a, b]

// This was my solution:

const fn2 = (a, b) => Symbol.iterator in a ? [...a, b] : [a, b];
```