# JavaScript - adding properties to an object using the spread syntax within a ternary statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to conditionally append different headers to my request object. I don't want to use `if/else`.

The following `...` gives syntax error `expression expected`.

I've looked at some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45184992/8518207) examples on SO but they don't seem to work. I just can't get my syntax right.

`headers` is some object that comes from function args which may or may not exist.

What is the correct way to write this?

```
    const req = {
      meta: {
        id: "asd123"
      }
    }

    {...req.meta, ...( headers ? headers : { "Content-Type": "application-json" })}
```

I want my output to look something like this

```
    const req = {
      meta: {
        id: "asd123"
      }
      headers: {
        ContentType: "application-json",
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `req` as complete object for spreading and a new `headers` property.

```
result = { ...req, headers: (headers || { "Content-Type": "application-json" }) };
```

If you like to use [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), you need to update `headers` first.

```
headers = headers || { "Content-Type": "application-json" };
result = { ...req, headers };
```

Comment: import React, { Component } from "react";
class Testt extends Component {
  obj = { user1: "vijay", imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.obj.imageUrl}></img>
        {/* <h1 {this.obj.user1}> </h1>; // error : '...' expected */}
        <h1 {...this.obj.user1}> </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Testt;
why does it ask me to use spread operator at h1 tag but not for img tag ? @Nina Scholz

Comment: @vijaykiranreddy, i have no idea of react.

Answer (score 1):

If you just typed this line

`{...req.meta, ...( headers ? headers : { "Content-Type": "application-json" })}`

Into your IDE, this is not an expression. You should assign it to a variable or use it in another way. The ternary part seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```js
{...req, headers: headers || { "Content-Type": "application-json" }}
```

`req.headers` will be assigned to headers if it exists or `{ "Content-Type": "application-json" }` if not.

Answer (score 0):

As header is coming as a funtion's args - you can first default initialize that header with undefined. Then just try this code -

if header is present then simply destructure it -
{...req.meta, ...( headers ? {headers} : { "Content-Type": "application-json" })}

Answer (score 0):

Code Readability has its own importance. Thus, I find below solution as most appropiate:

req.headers = headers || { "Content-Type": "application-json" }

Also, You can use Nullish coalescing operator '??' as below :

req.headers = headers ?? { "Content-Type": "application-json" }

But, '??' is a recent addition to the language. Old browsers may need polyfills.