# How can I pass an array's elements as individual arguments to a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is like this (but with more parameters):

```
function do_something(n1, n2, n3){
    return((n1-n2)*n3);
}
```

And then I have an array which contains 3 items, and are the parameters of that function:

```
my_array = [10,123,14];
```

For example,

```
 do_something(my_array[0], my_array[1], my_array[2]);
```

The following is probably not valid code for JavaScript but I want something like this,

```
 do_something(for(var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++){
                  add_parameter(my_array[i]);
              });
```

So, is there any efficient way to make the elements of the array the parameters of function?

Comment: This is the purpose of the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I know it's pedantic but it's *syntax*, not an operator, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44934830/5647260

Comment: @AndrewLi Tell that to MDN, I'm just adhering the text based on the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) introduced in ES2015:

```
do_something(...my_array);
```

This will *spread* the elements of `my_array` as individual arguments to `do_something`. If `my_array` contains `10, 123, 14` it will be equivalent to calling `do_something(10, 123, 14)`.

Of course, you can still use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) if you want support for Internet Exploder for the ES5 version:

```
do_something.apply(null /* the this value */, my_array);
```

`apply` essentially does the same thing. It takes in an array of arguments and executes the given function with those arguments as individual arguments to the function (and `this` value).

Answer (score 4):

Use [Function.Prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

`do_something.apply(null, myArray);`

or using ES2015/ES6 use spread as mentioned in the other answer

`do_something(...myArray)`;