# In Google Sheets, how can Array elements be passed as individual arguments to a Google Sheets native function?

Tags: google-sheets

My question is very similar to the one described here: [How can I pass an array's elements as individual arguments to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666498/how-can-i-pass-an-arrays-elements-as-individual-arguments-to-a-function)
The twist here is doing it inside Google sheets. In column A, there are a series of entries, from which I want to filter those that match certain criteria, and then in some other individual cells, populate the n-th result of the filter.

**COL A1:A4**

John A

Hector C

Mario G

Hecate J

**Cell C4**: `=CHOOSE(1,FILTER(A1:A4, LEFT(A1:A4,1)="H"))`

**Cell D8**: `=CHOOSE(2,FILTER(A1:A4, LEFT(A1:A4,1)="H"))`

But what happens is that **C4:C5** are populated with *Hector C* and *Hecate J*, and **D8** returns *"Error Function CHOOSE parameter 1 value is 2. Valid values are between 1 and 1 inclusive."*

My conclusion is that the Array that FILTER returns, is simply taken as a single argument by the CHOOSE function, instead of taking the individual elements as arguments.
I tried fiddling with the ArrayFormula, but no luck. I tried the long shot of preppending the "..." and obviously is not recognized as a function.

Any ideas that do not involve writing my own Script function?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! I posted my answer. Let me know if it helped you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @Marios, yes, it did. Should have thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [index()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) instead:

Then you can select the n-th element of the list like that:

```
=index(FILTER(A1:A4, LEFT(A1:A4,1)="H"),2)
```

Instead of having 2 as a hardcopy number you can also specify the length of the list to take for example the last element of the filtered list:

```
=index(FILTER(A1:A4, LEFT(A1:A4,1)="H"),COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A4, LEFT(A1:A4,1)="H")))
```