# What purpose does the spread element serve here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm learning react from a book and in an example the author made a component render this way

```
return (
        <div className="star-rating">
        {[...Array(totalStars)].map((n,i)=>
            <Star key = {i} selected={i<starSelected} onClick={()=>this.change(i+1)} />
        )}
        <p>{starsSelected} of  {totalStars} stars </p>+
    )
```

What purpose does the spread element serve here when initializing the array?

Comment: Personally, if I were writing this, I'd do `{Array.from({length: totalStars}, (n, i) => ` instead, which may make it a little clearer.

Comment: There is no such thing as a spread *operator*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array(totalStars)` makes an array with `totalStars` number of empty slots.  Using the spread operator coerces the empty slots into `undefined`, effectively filling the array with SOMETHING to be mapped over (even if it is undefined).

Just instantiating an Array with `Array()` doesn't put anything in it's spaces, just allocates the space for them.

Comment: cool, shorter than my current go to, which would be `Array.from({length:totalStars})` :p

Comment: It is a bit shorter, but Array.from is more semantic and a bit less hacky in my opinion.

Comment: Using the `Array` constructor with the `arrayLength` parameter doesn't actually allocate any memory for the "empty slots", it just sets the initial value for the `length` property. Arrays in JavaScript are sparse, meaning it will only allocate memory for indexes that have actually been set.

Comment: Please [don't call it spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/218196).

Answer (score -3):

Spread operator means when we want things to be spread in form of array like -

`function ABC (...) {`

`console. log(...); //this will print as array [1,3,5]`

`}`

`ABC(1,3,5);`

When we make call to function,  we are just passing as parameters not as array. But they coverted into form of Array with spread operators.

Comment: `console. log(...); //this will print as array [1,3,5]` no it wont

Comment: There are no anonymous parameters.