# Why I'm getting `this.state.expenseItems.map is not a function`?

Tags: reactjs

**This is what I have:**

### In AddExpenseForm component:

some sample data:

```
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      expenseItems: [{
          uid: '222',
          date: '10-10-2017',
          desc: 'desc1',
          amount: 'amount1'
        },{
          uid: '333',
          date: '01-09-2017',
          desc: 'desc1',
          amount: 'amount1'
        },{
          uid: '444',
          date: '06-05-2017',
          desc: 'desc1',
          amount: 'amount1'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

My addItem function:

```
addItem = (item) => {
  const currentState = {...this.state.expenseItems};
  const expenseItems = {currentState, ...item};
  this.setState({expenseItems});
}
```

then I'm passing it down to AddItemForm via `addItem={this.addItem}`

### In AddItemForm component:

My onSubmit:

```
<Form onSubmit={(e) => this.createItem(e)}>
```

then createItem function:

```
  createItem(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.addItem({
      uid: Date.now(),
      date: this.state.date,
      desc: this.state.desc,
      amount: this.state.amount
    });
  }
```

I'm iterating through expenseItems sample data and it shows up fine but when I try to add a new object (item) I get that error: `this.state.expenseItems.map is not a function`

I guess I'm doing smth wrong in my addItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of rest/spread <del>operators</del> isn't correct for what you're trying to do. Try this:

```
addItem = (item) => {
  const expenseItems = [...this.state.expenseItems, item];
  this.setState({expenseItems});
}
```

Edit: for reference, link to the [Spread <del>operator</del> syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: Ohhh. Brackets!! I recently came up with the same code but with {}. Thanks mate!

Comment: You're welcome. These new operators take a while getting used to.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling I've corrected it, but check out the URL of the link I've posted in my answer. Should someone go tell Mozilla?

Comment: MDN is community driven. The article itself was fixed but I don't know what it needs to update the URL.