# How to use an object property as a key inside of another object using react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

I am trying to set a part of the state inside a reducer but I need to access part of the initial state that is nested.

What I am trying to do:

```
  return {
        ...state,
        list: action.payload,
        filter: action.params,
        filter.totalPages : action.totalPages,
      };
```

This however does not working, I have tried doing filter['totalPages'] and it also does not work. How and what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: What is the value of `filter.totalPages`? Do you really want to use that value as a property **name**? That would be an odd choice based on the name. What do you expect the result to be? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use spread operator for filter object too

```
  return {
    ...state,
    list: action.payload,
    filter: {
       ...action.params,
       totalPages: action.totalPages
    }
  };
```

Comment: I dont know why I didn't think of this, love this answer, will accept when I can.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "spread operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/218196).

Answer (score 1):

```
return {
        ...state,
        list: action.payload,
        filter: action.params,
        [filter.totalPages] : action.totalPages,
      };
```

For more check [Computed property keys](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/) in es6

Answer (score 1):

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
      ...state,
      {
        list: action.payload,
        filter: {
          ...action.params,
          totalPages: action.totalPages
        }
      }
  })
```

It's problably missing `Object.assign` check it out

Comment: Where is `todos` suddenly coming from? `filter.totalPages : action.totalPages,` is still invalid syntax.

Comment: I'm sorry. I fixed that