# Babel fails to compile ES6 object cloning with spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I use *grunt-babel* to compile my ES6 code. But it returns `Warning: dist/app.js: Unexpected token (321:9) Use --force to continue.` when I try to use `{...obj}` to copy and extend object. Following code is working perfect in console of Chrome v61 but Babel doesn't like it. What is the problem?

```
let a = { a: 12 };
let b = { ...a, b: 15 };
```

I am using [env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) preset. (*babel-core v.6.26.0* and *babel-preset-env v.1.6.1*)

Comment: What version of Babel, what babel presets are you using, how are you compiling? You left a lot of questions unanswered...

Comment: Yeah, same issue. I worked around temporarily using `Object.assign({}, )` but would like to know a solution.

Comment: *babel-core v.6.26.0* and *babel-preset-env v.1.6.1*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spread property for objects is not part of ES6. Currently, as of Dec 2017, it is part of the stage 3 proposal for ECMAScript. You can [have a look at the proposal here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread).

You need a babel preset that includes features not yet officially in the language. The `babel-preset-env` does not include those features.

To solve your problem, you could use something like [babel-preset-stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) and add "stage-3" to the list of presets in your `.babelrc`.

*Side note:*

An alternative to the spread syntax for objects in ES6 is to use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let b = Object.assign({}, a, { b: 15 });
```

Comment: You mean the spread operations are not allowed? But I am able to do `k = {...a}` just fine. Only the combining of two objects is posing a problem.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi Again, it depends on what preset(s) you're using.

Comment: I'm using *env* preset (second JSON from these examples https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/ )

Comment: @micobg currently (Dec 2017), the spread operator is not included in `babel-preset-env`

Comment: @nbkhope, can you share a link where I can check which futures are supported by aech preset?

Comment: I couldn't find a specific list of presets, but there is this list of proposals for tc39: https://github.com/tc39/proposals (I found through the more resources section of the article (at the bottom) https://benmccormick.org/2015/09/14/es5-es6-es2016-es-next-whats-going-on-with-javascript-versioning/ )

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/218196). Rest arguments, spread parameters and rest/spread elements are all part of ES6 btw. Only rest/spread **properties** are not. @micobg: `preset-env` only contains transforms for features that have been officially released.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you so much for pointing that out. I have corrected the answer. Please let us know of any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to add these plugins to your `.babelrc`. This **Github** issue has a lot of solutions [**unexpected token (rest spread operator)**](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170). I am trying these out now.

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring`

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`

Answer (score 0):

I was using an outdated version of ChromeHeadless due to Puppeteer v1, and updating to v16 (for node 16) removed the "Unexpected token '.'" error.