# JavaScript - Object.assign to Spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

I initialize my component with this constructor :

```
constructor($q, $state) {
  'ngInject'
  Object.assign(this, { $q, $state })
}
```

the simple equivalent of

```
this.$q = $q
this.$state = $state
```

What is it alternative with Spread operator ?

Comment: I'd argue that the second snippet is by far simpler :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. You can only use spread syntax when creating a new object with literal syntax. You don't do that when you use a constructor.

Btw, there is [no spread "operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572), and object spread syntax is not part of ES6.