# Operator precedence for JS spread and rest operators?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm curious what the precedence of the Spread and Rest operators are in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

I was trying to find them on MDN's Operator Precedence table (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) but unless they are a subcategory of an existing operator type, I don't see them. I couldn't find any other obvious documentation about it.

Comment: It had been part of that table [since 2014](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence$compare?to=613269&from=612097) but I fixed it [last month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence$compare?to=1346329&from=1346230) :-)

Comment: @Bergi: thank you! I can’t believe someone added that to the table o_O but who knows, things were still in flux in 2014

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Spread syntax is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572) and therefore does not have a precedence.

It is part of the array literal and function call (and object literal) syntax.

Similarly, rest syntax is part of the array destructuring and function parameter (and object destructuring) syntax.

Comment: I guess that was the source of my confusion. Thanks for the quick answer! Hopefully it is more Googleable now. I had someone mention it in code review and suggest parentheses and it made me question how it got evaluated.

Comment: Parenthesis? No, definitely not.

Comment: I was trying to see if I can do this: `func(...args || [])`.  It works

Comment: @HaiPhan Yes, you can do `func(...anyExpression)` where the only limitation to *any expression* is that it must not be a comma operator expression (which would count as an argument delimiter instead).

Comment: IIUC, This is like saying is that it has a lower precedence than all operators. It applies to the fully-evaluated expression following it up to the closing `]`.

Comment: @einpoklum Imo it doesn't make sense to assign a "precedence" to it. That is only done for unary and binary operators whose nesting is otherwise ambiguous - but it is not for `...`. Sure, you could also consider `[`, `]`, `,`, `[...` and `,...` as "operators", then it might make sense to say they have a precedence level similar to that of other grouping operators `(`, `)`.

Comment: @Bergi: But it's ambiguous at least to the reader, e.g. whether `[ ... foo OP bar ]` means ` [... (foo OP bar)]`, or whether it means `[ ((... foo) OP bar) ]`. Now, I realize that the ellipsis is not separable from the parentheses - but that is not clear to the reader, who knows that separate parentheses _do_ exist in Javascript, e.g. `[ some_expression ]` yields an array of length 1.