# Use spread syntax instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, spread-syntax

I'd like to reduce this code using the spread syntax to remove the for loop, any ideas?

```
function shiftChar() {
  let aCharArray = prompt("Enter a word").split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < aCharArray.length; i++) {
    aCharArray[i] = String.fromCharCode(aCharArray[i].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  }
  alert(aCharArray);
}
```

This doesn't work

```
function shiftChar() {
  let aCharArray = prompt("Enter a word").split("");
  aCharArray = String.fromCharCode(...aCharArray.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  alert(aCharArray);
}
```

Comment: how about using .map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every element in your array you are doing some manipulation, `charCodeAt(0) + 1`, so it is probably best you use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> `map` calls a provided `callback` function **once for each element** in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

You can use the [spread *syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in order to update the contents of your variable `aCharArray` from the array.

> **Spread syntax** allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments

```
function shiftChar() {
  let aCharArray = prompt("Enter a word").split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  aCharArray = String.fromCharCode(...aCharArray);
  alert(aCharArray);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Spread syntax ([it's not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572)!) is not a replacement for loops, it's a replacement for [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

You can do

```
const string = prompt("Enter a word");
const charCodes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < aCharArray.length; i++) {
    aCharCodes[i] = aString.charCodeAt(i) + 1;
}
```

though and then use

```
String.fromCharCode(...charCodes)
```

instead of

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(String, charCodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

A minified solution not using spread:

```
function shiftChar() {
    alert(
      prompt("Enter a word").split("")
      .map(letter => String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + 1));
    );
}
```

A (strange) minified solution using spread:

```
function shiftChar() {
    alert(
      [...prompt("Enter a word")].map(letter => ( 
        String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
      )
    );
}
```