# Another es2016 estrange code that runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In the next code:

```
     return connectDropTarget(
         <div style={{ ...style, backgroundColor }}>
             {`Works with ${allowedDropEffect} drop effect`}
         <br />
         <br />
             {isActive ? 'Release to drop' : 'Drag a box here'}
         </div>,
    )
```

what is the use of   ...style    for? I can't see any variable declared as style.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: if there is no `style` object declared this will throw an error

Comment: That's not ES6 (or ES7) at all. It's jsx syntax.

Comment: but at the end it seems we get to mixture everything... is React es2015? my webpack tell me yes:  presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'] }

Comment: @Bergi Yes it is es6. It's not JSX at all.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda The xml syntax (`<div …`) and the braces for the `style={…}` and `{isActive ? …}` definitely are JSX (which also has its own spread syntax). The object literal in the style property (`{ ...style, backgroundColor }`) uses [spread syntax](http://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html) that will be part of ES2018. There's no ES6 involved.

Comment: @Bergi It's been a part of es6 for a while now though https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread. Is this something different?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda That's the proposal that got accepted for ES2018. ES6 was released in 2015. It did not contain rest/spread properties for objects.

Comment: @Bergi Okay that is too confusing. Is there a single place where I can view all of the changes between versions?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda The [spec intro](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-intro) has a short overview, for a definite table see the [finished proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) in the [TC39 proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) repo. Minor/editorial changes are [managed in the spec repo](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues), though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) that is being used to copy the contents of an existing `style` object and then adding/overwriting a `backgroundColor` property.

```
const styles = {
    position: 'relative',
    top: 0,
    left: 0
};

const backgroundColor = {
    background: '#FFF'
};

const newStyles = {...styles, backgroundColor };

console.log(newStyles);
// newStyles
// {
//  position: 'relative',
//  top: 0,
//  left: 0,
//  background: '#FFF'
// }
```

It can also be used to overwrite existing properties, but keep the others untouched:

```
const styles = {
    position: 'relative',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    background: '#222'
};

const backgroundColor = {
    background: '#FFF'
};

const newStyles = {...styles, backgroundColor };

console.log(newStyles);
// newStyles
// {
//  position: 'relative',
//  top: 0,
//  left: 0,
//  background: '#FFF'
// }
```

So it's basically an es6 shorthand for `Object.assign`.

Comment: [Spread is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the props of `style` will be passed as they exists

The style and background might already exists in your page :

```
const style = {fontSize: "9px", backgroundColor: "red"};
```