# How to remove specific element from a array or object using ES6 spread operators and rest operators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I want to do something like this.
There is object like

```
obj = { a: "xxx", b: "xxx", c: "xxx", d: "xxx", e: "xxx", f: "xxx" }
```

There i want to remove the values of property `c` and `d`  and to put them in array like `arr = ["xxx" , "xxx"]` . Then I want to add this array to the `obj` object as

```
obj = { a: "xxx", b: "xxx",  c: ["xxx", "xxx"], e: "xxx", f: "xxx" }
```

so is there way to this using ES6 spread and rest operators

How to do so if i have to remove values of n number(unknown it can be a 1 or 2 or 3 ..) properties and put them in array like above i have explained

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why 'f' was added to your new json obj?

Comment: @G_S I was there. Just on new line due to incorrect formatting.

Comment: If the properties and their number are unknown, you cannot use rest/spread syntax.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572), and object rest/spread properties is not part of ES6. It's coming with ES9 this year.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using destructuring and temporary consts.

```js
const obj = {a:"xxx" , b:"xxx", c:"xxx" , d:"xxx" , e:"xxx", f:"xxx"}

const { c, d, ...rest} = obj; // pick props you want to remove and keep rest

// create a new object by spreading `rest` and adding new property
console.log({...rest, c: [c, d]});
```