# How to push into an array of object using the spread operator to a specific element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array  as such

```
const arr = [a={} , b={}]
```

Now I know the spread operator is not for mutation or pushing but it is very easy to do so with.

I want this button to add elements to `a` when it's pressed

```
 <Button
title= {this.props.title}
 onPress={ this.roomNumberPressed }
 />
```

so the end results be something like :

```
arr = [a={1,2,3} , b={3,4,5}]
```

Comment: Note: `...` isn't, and can't be, an operator, neither when used for spread nor rest. It does things operators cannot do. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-foo-an-operator-or-syntax/44934830#44934830).

Comment: `const arr = [a={} , b={}]` isn't valid syntax. Do you have an array, or an object with `a` and `b` properties?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `{a: [], b: []}`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I want this button to add elements to `a` when it's pressed

As you said in your question, spread notation isn't for adding to existing objects. Your options are:

1. Use spread to create a **new** object and assign that new object to `a`:

   ```
   a = {...a, ...theNewPropertiesToAdd};
   ```
2. Use `Object.assign` to add new properties to the **existing** `a`:

   ```
   Object.assign(a, theNewPropertiesToAdd);
   ```

Note I've just used `a` above because your `const arr = [a={}, b={}]` is a syntax error, and I can't tell whether you mean `const arr = [{}, {}]` (in which case `a` above is `arr[0]`), or `const arr = {a: {}, b: {}}` (in which case `a` above is `arr.a` [and `arr` isn't an array]).

Comment: @Kuchi - You don't "append" things to variables. You assign them.