# Template Literal js

Tags: javascript, templates

I cannot understand this code what is the meaning of `values[0]` and `values[1]`

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

function foo(strings, ...values) {
  let a = values[0];
  let b = values[1];
  return `Sum ${a + b}
    Product ${a * b} 
    Division ${b / a}`;
}

console.log(foo`Num1 ${a + 10}
    Num2 ${b * 2} 
    Num3 ${b / a}`);
```

Comment: I assume you have a typo in the code? Missing `(` ?

Comment: @epascarello No, ``foo`a template literal` `` is valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The spread operator (...) used like that will take a bunch of arguments and convert them into an array.

if I said:

```
function foo(...args) {
  //do something
}
```

and then called it by saying:

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

args (inside the actual function) would be equal to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
In your example, values is an array, and it's obtaining the first value (values[0]) and the second value (values[1]) from that array.

Comment: Note: `...` isn't, and can't be, an operator, neither when used for spread nor rest. It does things operators cannot do. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-foo-an-operator-or-syntax/44934830#44934830).

Answer (score 2):

A tag function is called with an array of the strings in the template as its first argument, and then discrete arguments with the value of each placeholder. The *rest parameter* (`...values`) gathers up all values passed from the second (in your case) argument onward into an array. So `values[0]` is the value of the first placeholder in the call to `foo`, and `values[1]` is the value of the second placeholder.

There's no good reason for using `...values` in `foo` just to then get `a` and `b` from `values`, it would be simpler and perhaps clearer to just declare `a` and `b` as named parameters:

```
function foo(strings, a, b) {
  return `Sum ${a + b}
    Product ${a * b} 
    Division ${b / a}`;
}
```

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

function foo(strings, a, b) {
  return `Sum ${a + b}
    Product ${a * b} 
    Division ${b / a}`;
}

console.log(foo`Num1 ${a + 10}
    Num2 ${b * 2} 
    Num3 ${b / a}`);
```

Comment: I can understand what do you mean but i cannot understand the result of this code

Comment: How can sum result to be 35 not 15 and product to be 300 not 50??

Comment: @MostafaHamed - In general, the best way to understand these sorts of things is to step through them statement-by-statement in the debugger. The code is using `a` and `b` locally within `foo`, *shadowing* (hiding) the outer `a` and `b`. `foo` gets called with the value of `${a + 10}`, which is 15 (the outer `a` is 5), and `${b * 2}`, which is 20 (the outer `b` is 10). So the sum is 35, the product is 300, and `b / a` (`20 / 15`) is `1.3333333333333333`.

Comment: Thanks i understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

The three dots (...) is called the spread syntax. It's a neater way (especially arrays) to pass arguments to a function.

In your caseL

```
console.log(foo`Num1 ${a + 10}
    Num2 ${b * 2} 
    Num3 ${b / a}`);
```

You're calling the `foo` function here with 3 values 15, 10 and 2 which is passed to the function as `[15, 10, 2]`, so `values[0]` would be 15 and `values[1]` would be 10 and `values[3]` would be 2.

Answer (score 0):

This an example of tagged templates. You can use a function to parse a template.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

function foo(strings, ...values) {
  let a = values[0];
  let b = values[1];
  console.log(a , b); 
}

foo`x dwqdwq ${a} qwdqwdy ${b}`;
// prints 5, 10


function foo2(strings, a, b, c) {
  console.log(a , b, c);
}

foo2`x dwqdwq ${1} qwdqwdy ${2} mmdwldw ${3}`;  
// prints 1, 2, 3
```

`strings` will be an array of the string parts in the template.