# Push an object into the array using spread operator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object like this,

```
let array1 = [{id:1,name:'One'}]
```

whenever i do api call, the array of objects getting updated like this

```
let array2 = [{id:1,name:'One'}, {id:2, name:'Two'}]
```

for third time, it will be like this,

```
let array3 = [{id:1,name:'One'}, {id:2, name:'Two'}, {id:3, name: 'Three'}]
```

Now am trying to add key value pair for every object inside the array as

```
obj = {
    key: 'value'
}
[...array1, obj]
```

am getting an output like `[{id:1,name:'One'},{key: 'value'}]`

but the expected output is `[{id:1,name:'One',key: 'value'}]` that object should be pushed into an array after every api call

Comment: Why do you think this is possible with the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-foo-an-operator-or-syntax)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a key value pair to every object within the array, you need to map over the array apart from using spread syntax

```js
let array1 = [{id:1,name:'One'}]
const obj = {
    key: 'value'
}
array1 = array1.map(val => ({...val, ...obj}))
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the array items to be merged with the object, you can try with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) like the following way:

```js
let array3 = [{id:1,name:'One'}, {id:2, name:'Two'}, {id:3, name: 'Three'}];
let obj = {key: 'value'};
let res = array3.map(i => Object.assign(i, obj));
console.log(res);
```