# Spread syntax in Redux configureStore (Redux Toolkit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using `create-react-app . --template redux` and I want to use spread syntax inside the `configureStore reducer`.

Like this:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import aReducer from './a/slice';
import bReducer from './b/slice';
import cReducer from './c/slice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    a: aReducer,
    b: bReducer,
    ...cReducer
  },
});
```

Inside the `cReducer` which is in its own folder with `slice.js` and `utils.js`, I have a few properties which I don’t want to have in the separate object inside the store, but I want it to be at the root of the store.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: There is no "[spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator)". There is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: What's wrong with what you have ? Can you post your `c/slice` file

Answer (score 2):

The **intend of your question** is not clear. Are you having problem with the spread uses or how to compose the store object.

below are a few solutions based of assumptions:

1. If you want the properties `prop1` and `prop2` in the `configureStore` directly. just reference them and add them at the **root level** of store.

   ```
   import aReducer from './a/slice';
   import bReducer from './b/slice';
   import cReducer from './c/slice';

   const {prop1, prop2} = cReducer;

   export default configureStore({
     reducer: {
       a: aReducer,
       b: bReducer,           
     },   
       prop1,
       prop2,       
   });
   ```
2. If by root you meant in the `reducer` object.

   ```
   import aReducer from './a/slice';
   import bReducer from './b/slice';
   import cReducer from './c/slice';

   const {prop1, prop2} = cReducer;

   export default configureStore({
     reducer: {
       a: aReducer,
       b: bReducer,
       prop1,
       prop2,
     },          
   });
   ```

you can also alias the props:

```
    const {prop1, prop2} = cReducer;
    
    export default configureStore({
      reducer: {
        a: aReducer,
        b: bReducer,            
      },     
       c: prop1,
       d: prop2,     
    });
```

**Note:** BTW if you want the `cReducer` also in the object you can simply add that as well, as you already have.

If you wish to add a subset of props of `cReducer`, you can compose a new object using `lodash` `omit` function. see [omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit)

```
const cReducerWithout = omit(cReducer, 'propx')
```

and use the `cReducerWithout` in your store.

Answer (score 0):

From ES2018 (ES9) You can do this:

```
import cReducer from './c/slice';

const { dontWantThis, dontWantThis2, ...restOfcReducer } = cReducer;

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    a: aReducer,
    b: bReducer,
    ...restOfcReducer
  },
});
```

Check this article for more: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/#8-rest-object-after-destructuring

Comment: That doesn't work. I do not get `restOfcReducer ` object in the store at all.

Comment: If you used the latest create-react-app, it should come with this feature available. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#supported-language-features
Try create your project with `npx create-react-app . --template redux` to make sure you use the latest create-react-app version

Comment: @Zrna and you shouldn't, you should get properties of that object on your store.