# Square brackets and space in function declaration arguments Javascript

Tags: javascript, express

In Javascript what do the square brackets mean for declaring a function. And how can you declare more arguments with a space? Is this psuedocode?

`router.METHOD(path, [callback, ...] callback)`

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it spread "syntax" or the spread "operator"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator)

Comment: That's the documentation notation for optional arguments.

Comment: This notation is not part of the function declaration. It's a documentation convention.

Comment: it is a formal description of optional parts with [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form).

Comment: Wow that was quick! How did you know that @Barmar and Nina Scholz? Is there a nice article that runs through some examples?

Comment: @darkace Because I've been programming for 40 years and I've seen it in hundreds of documentation examples.

Comment: @NinaScholz tagging you

Comment: Do you know a good resource for getting more familiar with this @Barmar? I'm not entirely sure what to google here

Comment: Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this should be a comment, let me know.

In this particular instance, it's saying that you can pass in any number of middleware functions, separated by commas, *AND/OR* one single callback to be run as the last part of the method.

The square brackets sort of represent an "array" (though not really an array) of however many middleware functions you want to run before the final function call for the method.

The `space` after the square brackets is sort of an *AND/OR* character saying that you can pass however many middleware functions, AND a final function, OR just the final function without the middleware functions.

They're not declaring a function here, in the documentation. They're showing you "this is how many functions you can pass as middleware for this method which has been defined elsewhere: as many as you want, AND THEN the final function, or zero, AND THEN the final function"

Clear as mud?

Comment: Great! Only thing missing is declaring that this is just part of documentation style rather than javascript code.

And also what would be a good reference for this or phrase that I can google? Previous comments suggest EBNF but it's a bit abstract for my liking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Comment: You've got me there, man. I don't know what the specific term for this is. However I would be inclined to say that it's not restricted to only programming. I've seen similar examples in a lot of plain English where what can be inserted varies. Sort of like MadLibs

Comment: Well, I'm glad to hear it isn't just me that's a bit stumped! Thanks for the great answer