# How to pass all of an element's data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to be able to pass all of an element's `data` attributes, without have to individually specify them. For example:

```
function foo(elem) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(elem.data()),
    ...
```

However, when I simply supply `elem.data()`, nothing is actually getting passed. Is there a way to accomplish this without having to individually specify, like:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ foo: elem.data('foo'), ... })
```

Comment: The spread operator? `...elem.data`

Comment: From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data), it seems like what you've got should work...? (Provided you havent' added more `data-` attributes after the first time you used jQuery's `data` function on the element, since `data` is not just an accessor for `data-` attributes.)

Comment: @Silidrone - Just FWIW, [it's not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator). Operators can't do what spread and rest do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's what was really getting me, i thought for sure what i had should be working. So i just tried it again, and now it is. I could have swore this is exactly what i was doing last night, but idk.. it was very late XD

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So it's actual name is spread syntax?

Comment: @Silidrone - Or just "spread," but yeah, spread syntax, spread notation....

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery `data()` method I'm assuming `elem` here is a jQuery object.

You can use native elements [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property for this, like

`{...elem.get(0).dataset}` along with [`JS spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div');
console.log({ ...el.dataset});
```

```html
<div data-test-id="test" data-test-key="test-key"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the spread <s>operator</s> syntax:

```js
const foo = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c'
}

const boo = {
  d: 'd',
  e: 'e',
  f: 'f'
}

const foo_boo = {
  ...foo,
  ...boo
}

console.log(foo_boo)
```

Comment: I hope you understand that just consul login data itself alone will give you 100% same result in your snippet?

Comment: Yes I do. I put it for example purposes to show how it can be used. I constructed a new object with the properties of the data object by spreading it, and then printed it. In fact, let me edit it to make the example clearer for future visitors.