# How to duplicate property in JS constructor function without changing original

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, properties

I am new to JS constructor functions. I have an object/constructor. The function takes data as a property. However I need two copies of the data: one to change and then one as a reference to reset to. However, changing one seems to change the other no matter what:

```
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myFunction(myData)

function myFunction(data){
   this.updatableData = data;
   this.resetData = data;

   this.updatableData.pop()

   console.log(this.resetData)

   //expect [1,2,3,4,5]
   //but get [1,2,3,4]


}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the spread syntax to make a copy of the original array

```js
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myFunction(myData)

function myFunction(data){
   this.updatableData = data;
   this.resetData = [...data];

   this.updatableData.pop()

   console.log(this.resetData)
}
```

Comment: [It is not an operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator)

Comment: thanks for pointing it out I will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks. I've never heard of `spread syntax`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for a shallow copy.

```
this.updatableData = [...data];
```

Or [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
this.updatableData = data.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's called reference type.

When you change the reference, it affects all objects pointed to that address.

In good old javascript we used to copy arrays like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var arr_copy = [].concat(arr);

arr.pop(); // remove last item from the original array

console.log(arr) // prints [1,2,3]

console.log(arr_copy) // prints [1,2,3,4]
```

And this approach is still actual if you are looking for a cross-browser solution.