# Putting array elements in another by spread method (but a little differently)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I used another (my) way to store the elements of some array in another as a **spread** method.
I used join method for this way, but the array contains only one.
Here's my code:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArray = [eval(arr.join(', ')), 4, 5]

console.log(newArray) // [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561043)

Comment: `arr.join(', ')` = `"1,2,3"`. So `eval("1,2,3")` is the same as the code `1,2,3`. That's using the comma operator and gives you the last value.

Comment: thanks, I found my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArray = [...arr, 4, 5];

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` for that.

The `concat()` method will join two (or more) arrays and will not change the existing arrays, but instead will return a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArray = arr.concat([4, 5]);

console.log(newArray)
```

Another option is to use spread syntax (...) (introduced in **ES6**)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const newArray = [...arr, ...[4, 5]];

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: There is no destructuring in the second code. It's just spread syntax.

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat` was introduced in ES3, a long time before ES5.

Comment: @RanTurner VLAZ wrote spread *syntax*. [It's not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572) (or otherwise the OP's code might have worked)