# Add properties to an object in place, using the spread syntax

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The object spread syntax allows for merging an object literal with another object, as in

```js
const additional_object = { c:3, d:4 };
const object = { a:1, b:2, ...additional_object }; // object = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 }
```

However, I can't find how to use the spread syntax to augment an existing object with new properties, without creating a new object. Rebounding on the previous example, I'd like to write:

```js
const yet_another_object = { e:5, f:6 };
some_syntax_involving_object_here = {...yet_another_object };
// expected result: object = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6 }
```

It is easy to create a new object out of 2 objects (`const new_objet = { ...object, ...yet_another_object }`), but that is **not what I need**: the `const` reference to `object` must hold, and the `object` must get its additional properties. Note that `Object.assign` can be used to do so, but I'd assume the spread syntax can do the same in a much more readable way.

Comment: Use object assign, only real option.

Comment: [Spread is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572) - it's part of the object literal syntax, which always creates new objects.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I fixed my question accordingly; from the first comments, I have little hope that I can avoid `Object.assign`.

Comment: @Jean-ReneBouvier I don't see why you would want to avoid `Object.assign`. There is no `object ...= yet_another_object` syntax or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

`Object.assign(originalObject, newObject)` is what you are looking for. It will merge properties of the new object into the existing one, thus saving the reference.

Comment: I am explicitly asking for not using `Object.assign`…

Comment: Anything particularly bad with `Object.assign`?

Answer (score 3):

[There is no spread **operator**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator)

There is spread *syntax*. The important difference is that an operator can be used in any expression. Syntax is valid only in specific contexts.

[Object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) in particular is only valid within [an object initialiser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Which means you can only use it when creating new objects. Therefore, you cannot modify objects via spreading.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to make my hopes quite vain… I wish it were otherwise. Thanks anyway ;-)

Comment: If there is a specific problem with `Object.assign`, then there is probably a way to amend it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `Object.assign`, it’s just that the spread syntax is more readable.

Comment: `Object.assign(obj, a, b, c)` seems at least as readable, if not more than `obj¯\_(ツ)_/¯...a¯\_(ツ)_/¯...b¯\_(ツ)_/¯...c` (using a placeholder for some sort of "take the spread object" syntax). You can make a simple fluent wrapper that enables you to do `merge(obj).and(obj2).and(obj3).and({...obj4, ...obj5})` [like this](https://jsbin.com/qijilegowi/1/edit?js,console). It seems more readable, IMO.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible as yet in javascript.