# How to inject a new property into a JavaScript spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, spread

I am attempting to update an existing array of objects by adding a new object:

```
const oldArray = [{ name: 'First', value: 'one' }, { name: 'Second', value: 'two' }, { name: 'Third', value: 'three' }]
const newArray = [...oldArray, { name: 'Fourth', value: 'four' }]
```

My intention, however, is to set up `newArray` so that the Fourth object becomes the 3rd item (index 2) in `oldArray`. How can I go about setting up `newArray` so that the new object is injected as the 3rd item in the `...oldArray` spread operator, without having to write out all of the `oldArray` items again in `newArray`?

Comment: seems like you want splice if you want to control where it is added.

Comment: 1. [There is no spread **operator**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator). 2. Why exactly do you expect to use spread here at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.slice()` along with the spread syntax.

```js
const oldArray = [{ name: 'First', value: 'one' }, { name: 'Second', value: 'two' }, { name: 'Third', value: 'three' }]
const newArray = [...oldArray.slice(0, 2), { name: 'Fourth', value: 'four' }, ...oldArray.slice(2)];

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do two spreads using slice

```js
const oldArray = [{ name: 'First', value: 'one' }, { name: 'Second', value: 'two' }, { name: 'Third', value: 'three' }]
const newArray = [...oldArray.slice(0,2), { name: 'Fourth', value: 'four' }, ...oldArray.slice(2)]

console.log(newArray.map(x => x.name));
```

other option is to just use splice()

```js
const oldArray = [{ name: 'First', value: 'one' }, { name: 'Second', value: 'two' }, { name: 'Third', value: 'three' }]
const newArray = [...oldArray]
newArray.splice(2,0,{ name: 'Fourth', value: 'four' });

console.log(newArray.map(x => x.name));
```