# Function call with "options object" and shared parameters between multiple calls

Tags: typescript

I am calling a function using an "options object" but I would like to be more DRY. Currently, using a contrived example, I do this:

```js
// "options" being the options object
function refineMacroData(options: {file1: string, file2: string, file3: string, file4: string}) {
  // Do the stuff
}

// file2 and file3 arguments are the same in both branches for this context
if (isThisTrue()) {
  refineMacroData({
    file1: 'if this is true',
    file2: 'usually the same',
    file3: 'also usually the same',
    file4: 'also if this is true'
  })
} else {
  refineMacroData({
    file1: 'if this is false',
    file2: 'usually the same',
    file3: 'also usually the same',
    file4: 'also if this is false'
  })
}
```

What would be nicer is if I could, hypothetically, do

```js
// Same function as before
function refineMacroData(options: {file1: string, file2: string, file3: string, file4: string}) {
  // Do the stuff
}

const commonParams=  {file2: 'usually the same', file3: 'also usually the same'}

if (isThisTrue()) {
  refineMacroData({file1: 'something', commonParams, file4: 'another one again'})
} else {
  refineMacroData({file1: 'different', commonParams, file4: 'different again'})
}
```

However, the Typscript compiler says

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ file1: string; params: { file2: string; file3: string; }; file4: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ file1: string; file2: string; file3: string; file4: string; }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'params' does not exist in type '{ file1: string; file2: string; file3: string; file4: string; }'.

I get that this is not, technically, the same type but it looks like it should "fit" in there. Is there a way to "explode" the `commonParams` map so it can be inserted into the arguments? Thereby avoiding duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're calling "exploding" is known in JavaScript (and TypeScript) as *spreading*, which can be achieved via [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals), as follows:

```
if (isThisTrue()) {
  refineMacroData({ file1: 'something', ...commonParams, file4: 'another one again' })
} else {
  refineMacroData({ file1: 'different', ...commonParams, file4: 'different again' })
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUEMFsFNQGYFcB2BjALgSwPYtJAM6gBGsCOATrAFDLrZ6jUJYqwCykalOAIpAyQAFDgAOjFIQBcoAN6IsAG1gBGWYQyU2AcwA0ilQCYNW3QdYqAzKe0p9h2ABZbu0AF8AlPJqhQIUD4cUAwAC3hNJAQEGncaGjQ8TVBE6Gg8AAVIShhiAF55RxNQAHIkQiRIJSUATxDw0EIYWBKLZVgbUqrCYPLK6rqwiOaSjxoAE1g0JWz4ekxcfCxCABVQ5ZXKJFhhT1kSHBwVSBQAbnisBFBhDfXVrZ3PbzlfZnI2Tm5eASFhBUs1LISj04GFdK1QAA6aGpdIoLI5aCENoqFxdFA4IaUUB4eCQHSQNijLyxUCwJSEeAvPwsD5cHj8QQif7tdSlcaXBCwagoDAQ6GQ2GZbK5FHOIEc6Lc2C8ggEokeTyxGhAA)

Comment: Correct, but a minor note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator

Comment: ^ ^ okay, edited