# Cannot use spread inside conditional operator

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, operators, spread-syntax

Suppose the following:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const insertValues = [-1, 0];
const condition = true;

arr.splice(0, 0, condition ? ...insertValues : insertValues);
```

This throws a syntax error:

> Unexpected token '...'

I can get this to work by doing the following:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.splice(0, 0, ...[-1, 0]);
```

But this is obviously not what I'd like to do. How can I get the first example to work? I've tried including parentheses where I'd have thought necessary, to no avail.

Comment: `...(condition ? insertValues : [insertValues])`? The expression needs to be evaluated to a value to pass to `splice`, and if you make it e.g. `const thing = condition ? ...insertValues : insertValues;` it should be clear why what you've written makes no sense.

Comment: That's mostly because [there is no spread ***operator***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828). What you have makes about as much sense as conditionally calling a function via `fn if (condition) {()}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would work **if** `...` were an operator, but [it isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-it-spread-syntax-or-the-spread-operator) (and can't be), it's primary syntax. Operators can't do what `...` does. Operators have to have a single value result, but `...` doesn't.

So instead, you need to spread an iterable. You could do that by wrapping `insertValues` in `[]` when you want to insert it directly (your falsy operand to the conditional operator):

```
arr.splice(0, 0, ...(condition ? insertValues : [insertValues]));
// (Or you could use `unshift` if the index will always be 0 and you're never deleting anything)
```

(That may be what you meant later in your question. It's not an unusual idiom in cases where you want to use something as a series of arguments that may or may not be an iterable.)

Or just use an `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 1):

Spread ***syntax*** is allowed in a [handful of locations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#description).
Change your code to:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const insertValues = [-1, 0];
const condition = true;

arr.splice(0, 0, ...(condition ? insertValues : [insertValues]));
```

Or this:

```
if (condition)
  arr.splice(0, 0, ...insertValues);
else
  arr.splice(0, 0, insertValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place `...` before a conditional operator without parentheses:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const insertValues = [-1, 0];
const condition = true;
arr.splice(0, 0, ... condition ? insertValues : [insertValues]);

console.log(arr);
```

Since `...` is a syntax (a syntax operates on results of expressions), operators are evaluated before it, a more explicit example:

```js
console.log([... 'a' + 'b']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother with conditions and just want it work for both a number and an array, here's a solution that might be useful:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const insertValues = [-1, 0];
const condition = true;
arr.splice(0, 0, ...[insertValues].flat());
```

*This is based on assumption that the intention was `condition ? ...number[] : number`*

Comment: That has different semantics than the code OP has. The code in the question would either add two values `-1` and `0` or one value - the array `[-1, 0]`. This will just always add two values *regardless* of what `condition` resolves to.

Comment: For what I understand, OP may just want to either pass a single `number` or spread an array of `number` as properties. This could work if that's the case, otherwise it won't work if OP wants to pass an array as is.

Comment: When `condition = false` the code in the question would insert `[-1, 0]` as a value. There is no mention they'd want to add a single number. If that is the case, it's not what the question asks or describes. It's solely asking about spread syntax.

Comment: The two possible results are (a) the two values `-1, 0` prepended to the array (b) one `[-1, 0]` value prepended to the array.